How to Create a Composite Key Using Two Fields in JHipster?
I am learning JHipster and trying to create a relational table where the primary key is a combination of two fields. In the Liquibase changelogs, it looks correct, but when I run ./mvnw -Pdev, it generates incorrect SQL.
JDL
entity Category {
  name String unique
  createdBy String
  createdDate Instant
  lastModifiedBy String
  lastModifiedDate Instant
}
   

relationship ManyToMany {
  Category{parent} to Category
}

added_entity_Category.xml
  <changeSet id="20240607105313-1" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="category">
            <column name="id" type="bigint">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="true" unique="true" uniqueConstraintName="ux_category__name" />
            </column>
            <column name="created_by" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>
            <column name="created_date" type="${datetimeType}">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>
            <column name="last_modified_by" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>
            <column name="last_modified_date" type="${datetimeType}">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>
            <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-column - JHipster will add columns here -->
        </createTable>
        <dropDefaultValue tableName="category" columnName="created_date" columnDataType="${datetimeType}"/>
        <dropDefaultValue tableName="category" columnName="last_modified_date" columnDataType="${datetimeType}"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="20240607105313-1-relations" author="jhipster">

        <createTable tableName="rel_category__parent">
            <column name="parent_id" type="bigint">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="category_id" type="bigint">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>

        <addPrimaryKey columnNames="category_id, parent_id" tableName="rel_category__parent"/>
    </changeSet>

added_entity_constraints_Category.xml
<addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="category_id"
                         baseTableName="rel_category__parent"
                         constraintName="fk_rel_category__parent__category_id"
                         referencedColumnNames="id"
                         referencedTableName="category"
                         />

<addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="parent_id"
                         baseTableName="rel_category__parent"
                         constraintName="fk_rel_category__parent__parent_id"
                         referencedColumnNames="id"
                         referencedTableName="category"
                         />

Generated SQL
CREATE TABLE public.rel_category__parent (parent_id bigint NOT NULL, category_id bigint NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE
  public.rel_category__parent
ADD
  CONSTRAINT rel_category__parent_pkey PRIMARY KEY (category_id)

